# Как обработать ссылку в JSON формате в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый день! Изучаю JS на Freecodecamp. Но вот никак не могу понять как работать с JSON. Объясню: есть задание - необходимо сделать веб-страницу в котором при клике по кнопке должна выводиться цитата. Нашел веб-сервис который дает ссылку в котором при каждом обращении рандомно выводит цитату, автора, и тд в JSON формате. Вот ссылка: http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json Вопрос: как обработать эту ссылку и взять текст и автора цитаты и вывести на сайте при клике? Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш линк не использует HTTPS, поэтому не могу показать пример с вашим JSON.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
fetch("https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler")
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (var item of data) {
      let span = document.createElement("span");
      span.innerText = item;
      document.body.appendChild(span);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Clikc</button>
```